# Add range of numbers to each element in a list

Tags: python

I would like to add numbers to the end of each string in a list.
Example:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = list(range(0, 3))
```

Expected result:

```
c = ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'c0', 'c1', 'c2']
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension -

```
[i+str(j) for j in range(3) for i in a]
# OP ['a0', 'b0', 'c0', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = list(range(0, 3))
b=[str(b1) for b1 in b]
out=[a1+b1 for (a1,b1) in list(product(a,b))]
out
```